# JavaScript - Get only negative numbers form array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have task: Write the **function getNegativeNumbers (array)** which as an argument take array. The function has to return a new array filled **only negative numbers.**

I have done this solution, but I ask about different methods.

```
var myArray = [4, -5, 0, 2, -67, 8, 10, -34 ];

function getNegativeNumbers(array) {

    var negatives = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            negatives.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return negatives;

}
console.log(getNegativeNumbers(myArray));
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: This question make more sense for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `function getNegativeNumbers(array) { return [-1, -2]; }` - nothing in your requirement says that it has to use the argument array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following

```js
var myArray = [4, -5, 0, 2, -67, 8, 10, -34];

function getNegativeNumbers(array) {
  return array.filter(function(value) {
    return value < 0;
  });
}
console.log(getNegativeNumbers(myArray));
```

**ES6**

```js
var myArray = [4, -5, 0, 2, -67, 8, 10, -34];

function getNegativeNumbers(array) {
  return array.filter(value => value < 0);
}
console.log(getNegativeNumbers(myArray));
```

For reference - [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Array#filter` to create a new array of negative numbers:

```js
var myArray = [4, -5, 0, 2, -67, 8, 10, -34 ];

var result = myArray.filter(function(number) {
  return number < 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array.filter

```js
var myArray = [4, -5, 0, 2, -67, 8, 10, -34 ];

var negatives = myArray.filter(e => e < 0);

console.log(negatives);
```